# LINQ to Object collection of objects constraint on property

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a table that has 6 columns, and each column represents an `object`, so that each table row is a collection of 6 objects and each object has a property `color`.

How do I select all the rows that have no more than 4 objects of a single color in the row?

for example:

```
obj1.color=red, obj2.color=green, obj3.color=blue, obj4.color=green, obj5.color=blue, obj6.color=green
```

Comment: what have tried so far? add some code that u have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct an array with all objects in a row in it. Then group by color and check that all groups do not have more than 4 item in it.

```
var rows = tbl.Where(x =>
    new[]
    {
        x.obj1,
        x.obj2,
        x.obj3,
        x.obj4,
        x.obj5,
        x.obj6
    }
        .GroupBy(y => y.color)
        .All(g => g.Count() < 4));
```

Comment: I'm not very good with lambda syntax, or LINQ in general, when I run this  var rows = tbl.Where(x => new[] {x.g, x.d1, x.d2, x.c1, x.c2, x.rw1, x.rw2, x.lw1, x.lw2}
      .GroupBy(y => y.Color)
      .All(z => z.Count() <= 4));;
 rows.Dump(); i get an error in LINQPad that says "Constructed arrays are only supported for Contains.

Comment: and ur expression is not correct, test it. syntax error

Comment: u cant convert type to bool

Comment: Are you running the query against a database?

Comment: im running it on a query that is run on a database.  im querying a database with a linq statement to essentially give me all combinations of colors, and then im trying to select only those rows with less than 4 objects of the same color.

Comment: Then why you have said linq to objects on your question title?

Comment: the first query is run over a database.  the query im asking for help with is run off of the results from the first query, so I thought that it was an object, I apologize for the misleading title.

Comment: accepted the answer when adding .ToList()...  adding ToList() to solve the constructed arrays are only supported for contains exception is also good to know in the future.  Thanks for your help, I knew it was really simple, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a linqpad sample of how you could make that work:

```
// sample table
var table = new[] { 
    new {c1="blue", c2="red", c3="green"},
    new {c1="blue", c2="blue", c3="blue"},      
    new {c1="blue", c2="red", c3="green"},
    new {c1="red", c2="red", c3="red"},
    };  

table.Where(row => (
    new[] {row.c1, row.c2, row.c3}) // transform rows to array of vals
                .GroupBy(r => r) // group the vals
                .Any(r => r.Count() == 3)) // filter the groups
    .Dump(description: "I love LINQPad!");
```